# Contextual filter by month and year

Tags: 8, views

We have a site finally patched all the way up to 8.5.3. Our old site (8.4.0) was using a [Views patch](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2786577) (just for reference) that allowed for a content date field to be contextually filtered by month and year using a URL like https://example.com/events/042018, which returned all events for April, 2018.

This patch is no longer applicable to the Views module 8.5.3. It seems to be integrated for *Created Date* and *Updated Date*, but I don't need these fields. I am trying to access a content date field that I made.

Does anyone know how to do this?
Can you help me get started on creating a custom views contextual filter handler that can access this custom date field?

**Example of view:** Show all events filtering by date, but instead of an exact date, only grab month and year parts.

> [image: views content date month year]

Comment: views patch is probably not related to your issue. If you go to /admin/structure/views/ then find the view you are talking about, then click on edit. Take a screenshot of the view, or just the contextual filter area and add it here would be helpful. We need to know your view configuration

Comment: True was just using the patch as reference to the functionality we were using. I will add a screen shot of my view, but this is a very basic setup. Content, fields, one of the fields is a date, contextually filter view output by the month and year of this date field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views 8 is still developing the use of granular date filters for content daterange fields. This is needed for making month calendars, year calendars, etc.

**SOLUTION**

For Drupal 8.5.x Views, anyone trying to select content by MONTH & YEAR on a daterange field, install the following patch until it's integrated with core:

**[2786577-270.patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2786577-270_0.patch)**

https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2786577?page=1

Comment #318. For earlier versions of Drupal 8, simply scroll back in that thread and look for the patch applicable to your version.

**After installing the patch:**

1. Edit your view
2. Under Advanced > Contextual Filters > Add
3. Filter by "date"
4. You will now see all of your content date fields with date parts
   available as filters. Choose year_month or any other date part you
   want
5. You can now filter or contextually filter by date part
6. Important: Keep your eye on core updates as newer versions of this
   patch may need to be applied again

[image: contextual filter month year views drupal 8]
[image: contextual filter month year views drupal 8 calendar]

**Displays all content where the custom date field is anytime in April 2018. e.g. Display all events on calendar in April.**

Comment: That patch is not tested in 8.5.x, especially the update path.

Comment: True, but tested on 8.6 dev and confirmed on 8.5 by multiple including me. No update path, but still this patch is the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove your date contextual filter, by clicking remove.
2. click Add a contextual filter, and search for the date field and select the "Year+month" granularity. Then click add.

[image]

once you are done you should have your contextual filter look like this:

[image]

Now you can go `events/201807` and it would give you the same results.

update: this granularity is available for all date fields under the contextual filter option `(node.field_somedatefield (year_month)` provided the field has been added normally using content types manage fields section:

[image]

Comment: As was stated in the origin post and comments, this granularity is needed for a Content: Date field (a regular date field on the content type). NOT the Updated or Created date of the content, which is clearly supported. Thank you though.

Comment: This is available for all date fields provided you added them in the content type admin page as date field see updated section of my answer.

Comment: Sorry you are correct, but only datetime fields, not daterange fields. Which is still in dev. I should have been more specific about daterange field types in my original post.

Comment: @MattCampbell I see but in your question you did not even mention range fields. My answer gives you exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Worked for me today with a date field.